# Parsing complex XML using Ansible

Tags: xml, ansible

I am trying to parse an XML output by an powershell script which I need to parse as following and for which i am struggling from few weeks. Please someone help me. 
**xyz.yml which outputs the XML**

```
---
- hosts: win
  tasks:
    - name: Run the SPLAT PS with args
      win_command: powershell.exe D:\xyz.ps1 
      args:
        chdir: D:\
      register: splat
    - debug:
        var: splat.stdout_lines
```

The XML which is return by this is as follows:

```
    ok: [198.175.95.23] => {
    "splat.stdout_lines": [
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>",
        "<HostDiscovery>",
        "  <Host>",
        "    <MacAddress>33:77:90:88</MacAddress>",
        "    <DevicesPolled>78</DevicesPolled>",
        "    <ElapsedSearchTime>5.4112303</ElapsedSearchTime>",
        "    <ElapsedLookupTime>0.4844849</ElapsedLookupTime>",
        "    <Connection>",
        "      <NetworkDevice>",
        "        <MacAddress>33:77:90:88</MacAddress>",
        "        <DeviceName>sdd</DeviceName>",
        "        <Interface>Te1/1/1</Interface>",
        "        <IfType>6</IfType>",
        "        <AddressCount>189</AddressCount>",
        "        <Uplink>true</Uplink>",
        "        <Seen>true</Seen>",
        "        <Candidate>false</Candidate>",
        "      </NetworkDevice>",
        "      <NetworkDevice>",
        "        <MacAddress>33:77:90:88</MacAddress>",
        "        <DeviceName>kscjdsc</DeviceName>",
        "        <Interface>Gi6/36</Interface>",
        "        <IfType>6</IfType>",
        "        <AddressCount>8</AddressCount>",
        "        <Uplink>false</Uplink>",
        "        <Seen>true</Seen>",
        "        <Candidate>true</Candidate>",
        "      </NetworkDevice>",
        "      <NetworkDevice>",
        "        <MacAddress>33:77:90:88</MacAddress>",
        "        <DeviceName>ksxsk</DeviceName>",
        "        <Interface>Te1/1</Interface>",
        "        <IfType>6</IfType>",
        "        <AddressCount>327</AddressCount>",
        "        <Uplink>true</Uplink>",
        "        <Seen>true</Seen>",
        "        <Candidate>false</Candidate>",
        "      </NetworkDevice>",
        "      <NetworkDevice>",
        "        <MacAddress>33:77:90:88</MacAddress>",
        "        <DeviceName>fvfv</DeviceName>",
        "        <Interface>Gi1/0</Interface>",
        "        <IfType>6</IfType>",
        "        <AddressCount>176</AddressCount>",
        "        <Uplink>true</Uplink>",
        "        <Seen>true</Seen>",
        "        <Candidate>false</Candidate>",
        "      </NetworkDevice>",
        "      <NetworkDevice>",
        "        <MacAddress>33:77:90:88</MacAddress>",
        "        <DeviceName>vfevfvf</DeviceName>",
        "        <Interface>Te1/1</Interface>",
        "        <IfType>6</IfType>",
        "        <AddressCount>170</AddressCount>",
        "        <Uplink>true</Uplink>",
        "        <Seen>true</Seen>",
        "        <Candidate>false</Candidate>",
        "      </NetworkDevice>",
        "      <NetworkDevice>",
        "        <MacAddress>33:77:90:88</MacAddress>",
        "        <DeviceName>fvefvfev</DeviceName>",
        "        <Interface>Gi1/0</Interface>",
        "        <IfType>6</IfType>",
        "        <AddressCount>168</AddressCount>",
        "        <Uplink>true</Uplink>",
        "        <Seen>true</Seen>",
        "        <Candidate>false</Candidate>",
        "      </NetworkDevice>",
        "    </Connection>",
        "  </Host>",
        "</HostDiscovery>"
    ]
}
```

I need get the devicename from above xml where candidate==true and uplink==false.Basically the output should give output as devicename=kscjdsc in the above example as that is where the candidate == true and uplink==false.
Can someone help me how can I get this done through ansible playbook. Thanks fro your time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Ansible has an [xml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html) module that let's you parse XML with XPath expressions.

Comment: I tried to give the register variable value using xmlstring=splat in the below format xmlstring="{{splat}}" and mentioned xpath=/HostDiscovery/Host/Connection but it never worked till now.Can you tell me how can I use the XML module to achieve the above functionality.

Comment: Delete my latest comment which proved wrong so it does not confuse next users.

Answer (score 0):

The `xml` module can return either the text content of an element or an attribute value from an element.  If your xpath expression was `/HostDiscovery/Host/Connection` as you have indicated then you're not going to get the results you want: the `DeviceName` attribute is nested several levels below that point.  Something like this might work:

```
- xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ data.content|b64decode }}"
    xpath: "/HostDiscovery/Host/Connection/NetworkDevice[Candidate='true' and Uplink='false']/DeviceName"
    content: text
  register: result

- debug:
    var: result.matches|default([])
```

With your example input, this would produce:

```
TASK [get device name] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "devicenames.matches|default([])": [
        {
            "DeviceName": "kscjdsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Don't edit someone's answer in order to respond to it. Leave comments and/or update your question. The errors you are seeing don't appear to have anything to do with XML.

Comment: @pinkbask. you asked the same question again today in a new post. Why are your duplicating ? Your problem is that you are using `splat.stdout_lines` (which contains a list of all lines in your output) instead of `splat.stdout` (the output itself) as your xmlstring.